# Find Sharepoint Workflow Notification Error and Restart Workflow

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Just wondering if anyone can help me with this issue i am having. I am trying to create a Powershell script for sharepoint 2013. I am trying to get the script to search through all List item and within each item Workflow resend any failed Notifications found inside that workflow. Below is the script i have manage to get so far but it not working. Very New to Powershell, would be great full for anyone help on this thanks.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http:local-dev/sites/ab/ll"
$site = Get-SPSite "http:local-dev/sites/ab"


$ItemsList = $web.Lists["Returns"];


$Items = $ItemsList.items

ForEach ($Item in $Items)
    {



        If ($Item["Send Notifications"] -eq "3"){


            Write-Host Write-Host $Item["Name"] / $Item["Send Notifications"]

                    foreach ($wf in $Item.Workflows) {

                     #Start Workflow
                    $wfToStart= "Send Notifications"

                    $manager=$site.WorkFlowManager
                    $association=$ItemsList.WorkFlowAssociations | where {$_.Name -eq $wfToStart}
                    $data=$association.AssociationData

                    $workflow=$manager.StartWorkFlow($Item,$association,$data,$true)     
                    }








        }



    }
```